# What is a preferred string format for dates in a REST API

Tags: api, http, rest, date

What is the preferred string format for dates when it comes to REST APIs, for both request and response data?

I am considering ISO 8601 or RFC 1123:

```
 ISO 8601: 2008-02-01T09:00:22+05:00
 RFC 1123: Mon, 10 Dec 2012 14:25:01 GMT
```

What are the pro's and con's for each? Is there another alternative? What formats are other popular REST APIs using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ISO8601 looks much more useful. From [this document](http://www.hackcraft.net/web/datetime/#issue) (containing a number of documented formats, usages and pros/cons):

1. It is familiar to most developers
2. It is unambiguous
3. When sorted as a string of characters or as a string of octets they will be sorted as if they had been sorted as datetimes.